# Calculating a grade average

Tags: c, loops, do-while

My assignment is:

1. Enter the number of students in the class and then
2. Enter in a list of grades for them, then calculate the average for each student.

I have written the following program:

```
int main()
{
    int s, i, grade, total, gradenum, finalgrade;

    printf("How many students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    i = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter grade. Enter x when done.");
        scanf("%d", grade);
        total = 0;
        if (grade != 'x')
        {
            total = total + grade;
            gradenum++;
        }
        else
        {
            finalgrade = total / gradenum;
            printf("The final grade is %d", finalgrade);
            i++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= s);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that you get the number of students via user input, then the do loop should only repeat that number of times.

But when I compile the program, I get a warning message that 'total' is not used (when, as far as I can see, it is being used!). And then when I try to run the program anyway, I get stuck in an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong?

The class is Intro to C, and we have not covered cout, arrays or anything like that, so I don't think I'm expected to use them for this assignment. Loops (do, for, if/else) only.

Comment: You can't enter `x` when you use `%d` format for `scanf`.

Comment: From a quick glance: `total` is definately used. `gradenum` is used uninitialized. `if (grade != 'x')` is mixing up characters and integers. Got `if` inside the loop to control adding as well as the `do-while`.

Comment: You should display the actual warning message here

Comment: I don't get any warning about unused variables. The second argument to `scanf` should be `&grade`.

Comment: Are you getting any other error messages? Can you post the complete output of gcc? Sometimes if there is a syntax error further up in the code such as missing semi-colon or bracket this can happen ...

Comment: `x` is a char... I guess

Comment: You'll probably want to move `total = 0;` outside of your loop, too, or it won't be a total.

Comment: The warning is: 
"Warning W8004: gradecalc.c 26: 'total' is assigned a value that is never used in function main." 

That's the only warning or error message I get when I try to compile.

Comment: Also, if I move `total = 0;` outside the loop, won't that start a running total that will add everyone's grades together?

Comment: @TeraBat: Well, right now, you only collect one grade for each person, so you have no other total from which to compute an average. You're probably missing a second loop to collect the numerous grades from each person. Either way, you're getting that message because you do indeed never use that assigned value - the next iteration through the loop, you just reset it to zero again and throw that assigned value away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several issues, here:

1. You use `gradenum` uninitialized, and for the same reason you are not resetting it for each iteration, so your average calc will go wrong.
2. You initialize `i` with `0`, but continue until `i <= s`, so for 3 students, for instance, you actually loop 4 times.
3. You are missing a loop to collect the individual grades for your students.
4. `scanf("%d", grade)` should be `scanf("%d", &grade)`.
5. You're mixing integers with characters, easiest solution is to enter something like `-1` to quit, instead of `'x'`.

Here's a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s, i, grade, total, gradenum, finalgrade;

    printf("How many students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    i = 1;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter grades for student %d\n", i);
        gradenum = 0;
        grade = 0;
        total = 0;

        while ( grade != -1 ) {   
            printf("Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.\n");
            scanf("%d", &grade);
            if (grade != -1)
            {
                total = total + grade;
                gradenum++;
            }
            else
            {
                finalgrade = total / gradenum;
                printf("The final grade is %d\n", finalgrade);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (i <= s);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./grades
How many students?
3
Enter grades for student 1
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
77
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
68
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
71
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
-1
The final grade is 72
Enter grades for student 2
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
55
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
58
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
70
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
-1
The final grade is 61
Enter grades for student 3
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
22
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
25
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
30
Enter grade. Enter -1 when done.
-1
The final grade is 25
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```

which looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
char grade;
scanf("%c",&grade);
```

then compare.